# How can I get a single user's data from Firebase Auth REST API by email only, not by idToken

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

It seems based on these Firebase Auth docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-get-account-info that the only way to get user data via the Firebase Auth REST API is by using this route https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key=[API_KEY] and sending over the idToken (as well as the account API_KEY in the POST params). However what I need is the ability to obtain user data by sending an email address, and not an idToken (in addition to the account API_KEY in the POST params of course).

Is this listed in the docs elsewhere that I'm not seeing? I don't want to authenticate the user I'm referencing by email address, I just want the user's info (and I am authenticating via my account API_KEY and I would think that should be sufficient, no?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you will have to [sign in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password) first, passing `returnSecureToken=true`, get the ID token from the response, then lookup the account from there.  There is apparently no documented API for performing a lookup with email.

Or, you could use the Firebase Admin SDK to [look up the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) using `getUserByEmail()`.

Comment: Thanks Doug, the trouble is that I need this script to run independent from signing in and having an idToken. It's part of the flow Auth0 sets up for you to migrate over your users from another database seamlessly. So when a user logs in, if there is no Auth0 user matching, then they run your login script to check your other DB (in my case Firebase). A similar flow exists for getting user info. Both scripts are required for this feature. Trying to troubleshoot with them as well but anyways, their format expects that I can look up the user just by email. So that's my dilemma :/

Comment: Also since it's a script I'm adding to Auth0's app config page I don't have access to the the Firebase Admin SDK, that's why I'm using the REST API. For reference, in case it's helpful, this is what I'm trying to do https://auth0.com/docs/users/guides/configure-automatic-migration